# repeated IP's mysql

Tags: php, mysql, css, ip

need help.
i have categories and COMMENTS inside with IP addresses. 
i need to check all of categories on repeated IP.
if user use IP 2 times add css class (red) to user name, if use 3 times - another css class(green) , up to 5 times.

also i have container $comment['User']['ipaddress'] which show comment IP on site.
how can i do this with sql claim ?
thx

[image]

my connect to db:

`$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") OR DIE ('Ошибка подключения');
    mysql_select_db("books", $db);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ipaddress FROM comments, $db);
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);`

this code for one category. but i need to check all. And all user IP's are in one table.

```
if ($comment['User']['ipaddress'] == $res['ipaddress'])
    echo 'your ip repeated';
    else
    echo 'your ip is unique';
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and any attempt you have made to answer the question.

Comment: `IP != user`. Never has been, never will be. Consider that pretty much every single cell phone user on the planet is behind a NAT gateway of some sort. You'd be marking MULTIPLE users as the same person.

Comment: if 2 comments from 1 ip - need to pick out this user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ipaddress, count(ip) nb FROM comments GROUP BY pid, ipaddress HAVING nb>1
```

Comment: my original table - http://s019.radikal.ru/i608/1502/ef/a0af571ffedb.png      pid - it's name of categories.

Comment: Brigadier, i modified my answer to reflect your table, but that a job you should have done. If you want to group by categories AND ip just don't put the were pid=1, and group by pid, ipaddress.

Comment: @Adam not working in my case ( what i do wrong ? When i add 2 comments in one category i see - 'your ip is repeated'. But if i add 1 comment in 1 category and 2 comment from 1 ip in category 2 i also see 'your ip is repeated'. But i need this check in each separately. I think you understand me )        http://s020.radikal.ru/i701/1502/70/15fbc41223d0.png

Comment: if i undestand your need, which i'm not sure, you have to specify a where clause before the groupe by like "WHERE ipaddress=<yourip> AND pid=<yourcategory>

Comment: i have reviews site : ipaddress => user review ip . pid => company name. http://f-picture.net/lfp/s017.radikal.ru/i419/1502/0a/d222dd297e37.jpg/htm